# jquery Autocomplete from 1 ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I am trying to use autocomplete with data received from this ajax call:

```
    $.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url:"clientList.php",
         datatype:"json",
         success: function(result){
                  //what do i do here?
          }
    });
```

the data returned is:

```
{"1054":"Customer A","1055":"Customer B","1056":"Customer C"}
```

my autocomplete:

```
 $('#client').autocomplete({
        minlength: 2,
        source: //Result of ajax call
  });
```

how can i get that json result into my source?  I really dont want to do an ajax call every time a letter is pressed, the clientList.php result rarely ever changes.

Comment: how about loading your list during page load.

Comment: i do.  my question is how do i get the var "result" out of ajax function for use later on?

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is set the new source of autocomplete. For instance:

```
success: function (result) {
    $('#field').autocomplete("option", { source: result });
}
```

That way autocomplete will load the new options as soon as the Ajax call finishes with success. You can load the new options whenever you prefer using that sentence.

Here you have a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/DLLVw/810/) that you can use as an example.